# Can I pass variables from more specific template/preprocess function up to less specific?

Tags: views, theming

I need to display a node as a block, so I went with the most obvious way and created a view with a display block and this very node in it. But now I need to style it and I can't pick up the proper template. **block-views.tpl.php** looked great, but being in this template I do not seem to have access to view's variables anymore, have I? Basically I need a place where I could have access to view's variables and control over the look of the block. If I could just pass variables up the chain, that would be great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nodes In Block](http://drupal.org/project/nodesinblock) or [Node Block](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) can help to place nodes in blocks.

The other part, to theme that particular node can achieved by different scope of templates from general to specific node templates. e.g.

- node.tpl.php
- node-[type].tpl.php
- node-[nid].tpl.php

Comment: That is not that flexible, but it works. Thanks :)